# Basic Authentication with AngularJS (resource) and Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4

I am searching a way to pass the credentials to my laravel api.

Javascript:

```
app.factory( 'APIService', function( $resource, $http ) {

    http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + 'email:password';

    var data = $resource( 'api/v1/:route', {route: "@route"} );

    return data;

});
```

Laravel:

```
Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{

    return Auth::basic();

});
```

My solution does'nt work :(

Here is the POSTMAN Output:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8888/laravel-emt/public/api/v1/publications
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Authorization:Basic cm9iZXJ0LndhbHRoZXJAdHUtaWxtZW5hdS5kZTpjb21tYW5kZXIxNw==
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkhSOUVZcjk5NTJIemdvb1ErXC9FQ1g4TVdYSmp6UHpXejVIbjBodTdmcXlRPSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRTFBNWpHNGZ5OGRvQ3MxNFVkcm8ra2FINDBmdE01XC9RRWxJSitJMTBROE1tbFpuS1JIN1o1YjFyVnRPUHVSZFE2TUZEWHdZSFBsdzdnRkViVEt0cXd3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiI0MjFmYmNhZTM1NDliYzJiNTI5YTNhNTZkZGVlODE5OTg0MGZjOTdiYzJkM2I2YjkyMTQ4YjE2Y2ViMGY5N2FhIn0%3D
Host:localhost:8888
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Sat, 15 Mar 2014 17:11:46 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.3
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InpRVFwvZDliRWpsRE0xcmlDdnpoNm5wM25Md0QrM3l1NVFXaWtMZ0RIZmJZPSIsInZhbHVlIjoibkEyZDZ1b2REK1B6VlJXWVFVK1NlS1plbCtMNE1NUXZVU3BRWk5Da09qOGVLOTVSYkNLSmpJaldxM0F0clYxOW1kVUlUY1RNdDRqSFAydWQ1ZlF0ZkE9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImZiMDVlNTk1ZDYwNjQ0Nzg0ZTY0YTYyNWUwYTNmYWRlY2ZkY2JmNDYzYmJkYmZmMmQ0MGU0ZTQ5Y2U1MzhjM2EifQ%3D%3D; expires=Sat, 15-Mar-2014 19:11:46 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.3
```

and here is the AngularJS Output:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IlYwUDNUM01oSmJrWVwvTHAzQWQycmJ6Z25oaEgzaEJKR0ZLbzNPTVFIRDk0PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSmxzMG1URUNYTFBnZmRkNk9NcFQyb2JwNWJDaW5wVlU2YVZYeFo2bTQwbUc2cVM5OThtdEVSRmhPV25cL2dtOUZHbXZnekJ3NzNsS2dOWXNRTGJMZWNRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiIyYzZhOGNhNTM2MjJhNjVkMzkxZDM5NmYxOTIwYWQ1YmNhYzEwYjg4MmM3NjU1NzJhNGJhYmI0OTU2MzczMTNlIn0%3D
Host:localhost:8888
Referer:http://localhost:8888/laravel-emt/public/secadmin
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Sat, 15 Mar 2014 19:17:02 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.3
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkZiNXJBUmpaSU1RTkxNUHhaXC9mdEN3cHJ5REQ5aE9DajdXWCthMnBKN3ZNPSIsInZhbHVlIjoibXZjVjZ4dm1cL1lTY01XeEFHQyt2YmFBWWlFeWl2NVwvZm5iTlI4eG5UdHJBS003dkpreFJ1WU1qZldqQThndTRMWTN6dWRXVXhJelZOYWRQb1V0XC9nc0E9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjM3ZDFlNzc3MjBmZjk0M2UxZDY5NzFiMTc1YzIzYmVhODE1ZWM1MmVkZjEyYTRmMWNlMTgwYTA5ZDk3ODllMTkifQ%3D%3D; expires=Sat, 15-Mar-2014 21:17:02 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.3
```

I'am asked to input the password manually.

I hope these are the things you need to help ;-)

Best regards, Robert

Comment: What doesn't work about it? What error do you get? What is going across in the request? (Network panel in Chrome); are you getting console errors? are you seeing any server side errors?

Comment: There are'nt any error in the Cosole. But the Browser ask me to input the credentials. So i think i dont pass the credentilas in a correct way.

Comment: I recommend trying to build the request using POSTman for Chrome and making sure you have the right format. Then doing it for angular should be easy.

Comment: Thank you! With Postman it works fine. But i dont know how to get it work with angularjs.

Comment: We need the request you're making edited in to your question. Please give us the raw request that's generated both from the network panel when you run it in angular, and the network panel when you run it through postman, as well as the HTTP status code

Comment: Umm, we're missing the request and response headers.

Comment: i add the angular header after fill the credentials automatically...before there is no request or response...

Comment: any ideas? something i should do?

Comment: app.run(function($http) { $http.defaults.headers.common.Authentication = 'Basic username:password'}); not working, too. :(

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I'd guess that it's just a typo:

```
app.factory( 'APIService', function( $resource, $http ) {
        // should be $http.defaults
        http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + 'email:password';
        var data = $resource( 'api/v1/:route', {route: "@route"} );
        return data;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It works if you encode 'email:password' as Base64.